# Partitioning hard disk by having one partiton

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have a single partition of about 465 GB with ubuntu 13.04 installed on it. Now i want to make it dual boot and want to create partitions. How to do it? Thank u.

Answer (score 1):

Using **gparted partition editor** you can split a partition into two.It was done through gparted live-disk or ubuntu live-disk because you installed ubuntu on the 465 GB which was already mounted while you logging into ubuntu.

- Boot ubuntu live-disk,click on try ubuntu,then connect to the internet and openup the terminal.And run the below commands to install gparted

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install gparted && sudo gparted
  ```
- Right-click on the 465 GB partition then select the option Resize/Move.Now reduce the size of how much space did you want for another Os.
- After resizing,an unallocated space was created just below to the 465 GB partition.
- Now right-click on the unallocated space and click on the **New** option.From that Create ntfs partition for windows or ext4 partition for linux os.(choice based on your's)

Comment: can u please tell me how to make a gparted live disk

Comment: did you have ubuntu-live disk?